# Contact Form Sends me Empty emails

Tags: php, contact-form

I have this Contact form that works well. If someone sends me an email I get it. But for whatever reason I keep getting empty emails sent to me. Since no one could access that page im sure its not someone sending me the empty emails. I dont know what the problem is. Any help?

```
   <form method="post" id="contactform" name="contactform" action="comment.php" id="ContactForm" name="ContactForm" method="post">

    <fieldset>

    <label>Email *</label>
    <input class="text" type="text" name="email">
    <label>Name *</label>
    <input class="text" type="text" name="name" />

    </fieldset>

    <input class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

and my contact.php

    <?php


    $email.= "<b>Email     : </b>".trim($_POST['company'])."<br/>";
    $email.= "<b>Name      : </b>".trim($_POST['name'])."<br/>";



    //Replace YourEmailAddress@Yourdomain.com with yours, eg:contactus@mywebsite.com
        //Both on the next line and on the mail function below.
    $headers = "From: email@email.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
    mail(
            "Your Name<myname>", 
            "Header", 
            $email,
            $headers
    );
        header("www.google.com");
?>
```

the "header" part in my php form is to redirec the user to a page after sending the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your server logs to see if the content at least makes it that far?

Comment: It either works well, or it doesn't. Pick one?!

Answer (score 6):

You are probably getting visits from bots. Your script will always trigger an E-Mail, even if no POST data is present.

In your contact script, as a basic measure of protection, add something like

```
if ($_POST["submit"] != "Send") 
 die();
```

add further validation (as pointed out in the comments) as needed.

Comment: Weak protection, but a good start (and the +1 is for the rationale).

Comment: Wouldn't there usually be junk data if it was from a bot or not necessarily?

Comment: @Mad I mean a search engine bot doing a GET request, not a malicious one trying to send spam. Against a malicious one, this would indeed be too weak a protection as @Tomalak says

Comment: Also, validate the form fields themselves (that they aren't empty). Also, I'd put in a simple human validation field ("add these two numbers") in an extra field to try to knock down form bots.

Comment: I wasn't aware that crawlers followed form actions, is this correct?

Comment: @Mad they usually shouldn't. I guess it's either one that doesn't know how to behave, or one blindly guessing URLs.

Comment: Blindly guessing URLs? That is some pretty bizarre behavior!

Comment: Hi. I added the validation, lets see what happens.

Comment: any knows where i can find a simple "1 + 1" human vlaidation? .. I added the validation but im still getting the emails.. =/

Answer (score 3):

Might be because you don't appear to be validating the form inputs, so it can be submitted blank.

Sometimes I do this to websites (test validation, end up sending blank email), but I usually add a message later to "Validate your input!".

Excuse me if you are indeed doing validation, but that was my gut instinct because I see a lot of people fail to validate even the *presence* of a required input, let alone the integrity.

Comment: No, it's been my experience that most beginner scripters do not bother with validation. You have to be burned pretty good or have a strong business argument typically to "go through the trouble".

Comment: I don't do it to piss anyone off intentionally, I just like to see how other sites are handling form validation from a UI perspective, and the answer is often "They aren't"

Answer (score 1):

Company doesnt exist in your form but you try to parse it.

And maybe 2 form name declaration is not that good but its not your answer.